Merge two lists based on device Name
I have these two lists:
"list": [
            {
                "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx001.net",
                "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/10/0/42 to Gi1/10/0/45 Gi2/10/0/32 to Gi2/10/0/34\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
                "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
                "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
                "NO": "1"
            },
            {
                "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx002.net",
                "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/9/0/9 to Gi1/9/0/12 Gi2/9/0/9 to Gi2/9/0/11\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
                "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
                "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
                "NO": "2"
            }
        ]

and
  "json": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 1000,
    "search": {},
    "filter_op": "and",
    "total": 701,
    "fields": [
      "ID",
      "Name",
      "PluginKey"
    ],
    "data": [
      {
        "ID": 54,
        "Name": "inet-fw.lab.net",
        "PluginKey": "checkpoint_gaia"
      },
      {
        "ID": 2558,
        "Name": "uscx001.net",
        "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
      },
      {
        "ID": 2559,
        "Name": "uscx002.net",
        "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
      },
      {
        "ID": 2560,
        "Name": "test1.net",
        "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
      }
    ]
  }

Intention is create a new list which will contain first list with additional information ID and PluginKey from second list for found devices from second list, so it will look like as following:
"list2": [
            {
                "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx001.net",
                "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/10/0/42 to Gi1/10/0/45 Gi2/10/0/32 to Gi2/10/0/34\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
                "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
                "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
                "NO": "1",
                "ID": 2558,
                "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
            },
            {
                "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx002.net",
                "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/9/0/9 to Gi1/9/0/12 Gi2/9/0/9 to Gi2/9/0/11\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
                "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
                "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
                "NO": "2",
                "ID": 2559,
                "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
            }
        ]

I have been playing with combine, zip, map but it always gave me only one item instead of full list of items.
Could someone help me with this task please?
Ideally it would be perfect if we could use filters instead of loop, since I expect a very big list of thousands items - this example is just very small extract of data.

Does this give you what you want?
    - name: create new list
      set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list2 | default([]) + [item | combine({'ID': device.ID, 'PluginKey': device.PluginKey})] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
      vars:
        device: "{{ json2.data | selectattr('Name', 'equalto', item.DEVICE_NAME) | list | first }}"

    - name: debug it
      debug:
        msg: "{{ list2 }}"


The following is voluntarily verbose and detailed to be self explanatory. You can refactor at will once you get the idea. Note that this solution uses filters (although it uses some templating as well) and meets your requirement of not using unnecessary tasks.
This solution uses the community.general.lists_mergeby and ansible.utils.remove_keys filters. The collections are included in the ansible community pip package but you may have to install them if you installed ansible-core only:
# Check if collections are installed (example output on my current environment)
$ ansible-galaxy collection list | grep -E "(general|utils)"
ansible.utils                 2.12.0 
community.general             8.1.0 

# Install collections if needed
$ ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
$ ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.utils

The following playbook should be quite clear to follow:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your original `list` renamed to `device_list`
    # on a single json line for legibility
    # Note: `list` is definitely not a good variable name
    # as it may conflict with python builtin class name
    device_list: [{"DEVICE_NAME":"uscx001.net","IMPLEMENTATION":"system\nInterface range Gi1/10/0/42 to Gi1/10/0/45 Gi2/10/0/32 to Gi2/10/0/34\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force","POST_CHECK":"dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]","PRE_CHECK":"dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]","NO":"1"},{"DEVICE_NAME":"uscx002.net","IMPLEMENTATION":"system\nInterface range Gi1/9/0/9 to Gi1/9/0/12 Gi2/9/0/9 to Gi2/9/0/11\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force","POST_CHECK":"dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]","PRE_CHECK":"dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]","NO":"2"}]

    # Your original json on a single line for legibility,
    # encapsulated in a higher level var (as I guess you get
    # that result from a REST call to an API)
    some_uri_response: {"json":{"offset":0,"limit":1000,"search":{},"filter_op":"and","total":701,"fields":["ID","Name","PluginKey"],"data":[{"ID":54,"Name":"inet-fw.lab.net","PluginKey":"checkpoint_gaia"},{"ID":2558,"Name":"uscx001.net","PluginKey":"hp_aseries_alt_2"},{"ID":2559,"Name":"uscx002.net","PluginKey":"hp_aseries_alt_2"},{"ID":2560,"Name":"test1.net","PluginKey":"hp_aseries_alt_2"}]}}

    # Transform the list in json to rename key `Name` to `DEVICE_NAME`
    # In practice this is done in two steps:
    # - duplicate key `Name`to `DEVICE_NAME`
    # - remove the original `Name` attribute.
    # The goal is to get a common attribute
    # between the two lists. There are other options here
    # but doing it through templating is quiete adapted
    # in that case.
    transformed_json_list: |-
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% set transformed_result = [] %}
      {% for entry in some_uri_response.json.data %}
      {% set new_entry = entry | combine({'DEVICE_NAME': entry.Name}) | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['Name']) %}
      {{ transformed_result.append(new_entry) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ transformed_result }}
      {% endfilter %}

    # Merge the two lists on their common attribute.
    # Elements which are not common will remain in the result
    raw_merged_list: "{{ device_list | community.general.lists_mergeby(transformed_json_list, 'DEVICE_NAME') }}"

    # Filter out elements from json list wich were
    # not present in the list of devices. Here are
    # inferred that devices always have the `IMPLEMENTATION`
    # attribute set. Adapt if you need to be more specific.
    merged_list: "{{ raw_merged_list | selectattr('IMPLEMENTATION', 'defined') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show original device list (run with -v to display)
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: device_list
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show original json result (run with -v to display)
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: some_uri_response
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show json list with `Name` renamed to `DEVICE_NAME`
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: transformed_list

    - name: Show merged list before cleaning out unwanted elements
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: raw_merged_list

    - name: Final expected list cleaned out
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: merged_list

Running the playbook gives (add -v if you want to display your original vars)
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show original device list (run with -v to display)] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show original json result (run with -v to display)] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show json list with `Name` renamed to `DEVICE_NAME`] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "transformed_json_list": [
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "inet-fw.lab.net",
            "ID": 54,
            "PluginKey": "checkpoint_gaia"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx001.net",
            "ID": 2558,
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx002.net",
            "ID": 2559,
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "test1.net",
            "ID": 2560,
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Show merged list before cleaning out unwanted elements] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "raw_merged_list": [
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "inet-fw.lab.net",
            "ID": 54,
            "PluginKey": "checkpoint_gaia"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "test1.net",
            "ID": 2560,
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx001.net",
            "ID": 2558,
            "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/10/0/42 to Gi1/10/0/45 Gi2/10/0/32 to Gi2/10/0/34\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
            "NO": "1",
            "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
            "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx002.net",
            "ID": 2559,
            "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/9/0/9 to Gi1/9/0/12 Gi2/9/0/9 to Gi2/9/0/11\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
            "NO": "2",
            "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
            "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Final expected list cleaned out] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "merged_list": [
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx001.net",
            "ID": 2558,
            "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/10/0/42 to Gi1/10/0/45 Gi2/10/0/32 to Gi2/10/0/34\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
            "NO": "1",
            "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
            "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/10/0/4[2345]|2/10/0/3[234]",
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        },
        {
            "DEVICE_NAME": "uscx002.net",
            "ID": 2559,
            "IMPLEMENTATION": "system\nInterface range Gi1/9/0/9 to Gi1/9/0/12 Gi2/9/0/9 to Gi2/9/0/11\ndefault\nport link-mode bridge\ndescription *::HP-HSP::Available::::\nport access vlan 999\nshutdown\nreturn\nsave force",
            "NO": "2",
            "POST_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
            "PRE_CHECK": "dis inter brief | inc 1/9/0/9|1/9/0/1[012]|2/9/0/9|2/9/0/1[01]",
            "PluginKey": "hp_aseries_alt_2"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0   


Get the list of device names
  device_names: "{{ list | map(attribute='DEVICE_NAME') }}"

gives
  device_names:
  - uscx001.net
  - uscx002.net

The below declaration gives what you want
  list2: "{{ json.data | selectattr('Name', 'in' , device_names) |
             ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['Name']) |
             zip(list) |
             map('combine') }}"



You can omit the filter ansible.utils.remove_keys if you don't mind the redundant key Name.

